# Loading failed JavaScript file when deploy web application on weblogic

Tags: javascript, deployment, weblogic12c

I have a problem with loading a JavaScript file on a jsp page when I deploy my web application on a weblogic server. Before I deployed it on Tomcat 7 and it worked normally.

- First I see on console window of Firefox. My jsp page couldn't load js file on ***/resources/*** folder (this folder is the same level with ***/WEB-INF/***):

> Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “http ://10.3.11.25:7001/resources/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js”.  10.3.11.25:7001:104

Image I have capture:

[image: Console log of browser]

- I tried copying the url: `http ://10.3.11.25:7001/resources/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js` to the address bar.

I can access it, but I only can download the js file (It not display the source code on browser as normally).

What is my problem? I deploy my web application on weblogic 12c.

**UPDATE:**

- Network tab load js file ok, all status is 200:

[image: Capture image]

- Source code include on jsp:

`<script src="resources/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="resources/assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>`

**UPDATE 2:**

- All status is 200 but load O KB and response is notthing
- When I copy the js url to address bar it show popup download it (not display the source code as normally)

Comment: What you have written in jsp for including this javascript file. Also, show what is the network tab in console showing. A screenshot of a full web page including address bar will be useful to diagnose.

Comment: I have update in my post.

Comment: Why all js files are showing as blank i.e. 0B in size. Verify from here what this contains by clicking on it.

Comment: Also try to use include like this for all files <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: When i copy the js url to address bar it show popup download it (the js file full source code not blank) (not display the source code as normally)

Comment: I try to do add you say. But it nothing change.

Comment: Check on some other browser most suspicious thing here is why it is giving 0B size files. Have to diagnose that

Comment: I try use chrome. The result is the same but the console is more detail. It say:

"because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: a js file should not return mime type as application/octet-stream it should be application/javascript. Maybe server is not able to find the resource so its mime type is changes as 0B size reconfirms it. Check server log when you run the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve my problem. My web application can't read the js file beacause have problem with MIME type on weblogic.

I add following mime mapping to web.xml and problem has been resolved:

```
<mime-mapping>
      <extension>xml</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>

   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>js</extension>
      <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
```